# Iterate through JSON array putting into new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having problems iterating through JSON array with for loop (res2.data.list), grabbing three data points, and putting them into a new array. Getting error "forecast is not a constructor in fetchWeather".
How would I do this in a functional component?

```js
const fetchWeather = async () => {
        
      try {
        await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          savePositionToState
        );
        const res = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&units=imperial`
        );
        const res2 = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/forecast?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&units=imperial`
        );
        setTemperature(Math.round(res.data.main.temp));
        setWeather(res.data.weather[0].main);
        console.log(res2.data.list)

        // console.log(res.data, res2.data);
            for (let i=0; i < res2.data.list.length; i+=1) {
                const temporary = new forecast(
                    res2.data.list[i].dt_txt,
                    res2.data.list[i].weather[0].icon,
                    res2.data.list[i].main.temp,
                    res2.data.list[i].dt_txt,
                    )
            }


    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
```

Comment: is forecast an actual class you define somewhere?

Comment: I defined it at top
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);

Comment: Well, useState does not generate a constructor. You can not use useState like that. You can do like setForecast({txt: res2.data.list[i].dt_txt,
                    icon: res2.data.list[i].weather[0].icon,
                    temp: res2.data.list[i].main.temp,
                    otherTxt: res2.data.list[i].dt_txt,})

I suggest you to read Hooks section in React docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);` I'll assume you want `forecast` to be an array of objects with the specific properties from `res2.data.list` response array. `forecast` ***is*** the state object, it's not a constructor, so trying to invoke a `new forecast` won't work.

You can map the `res2.data.list` to a new array and update the `forecast` state.

```
const fetchWeather = async () => {
  try {
    await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      savePositionToState
    );
    const res = await axios.get(.....);
    const res2 = await axios.get(.....);

    setTemperature(Math.round(res.data.main.temp));
    setWeather(res.data.weather[0].main);

    setForecast(res2.data.list.map(item => ({
      text: item.dt_txt,
      icon: item.weather?.[0]?.icon,
      mainTemp: item.main?.temp,
    })));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to transform each element in res2.data.list into a new object, then set that new list on React state.

`.map` is used for 1-to-1 list transformations.

So `setForecast(res2.data.list.map(e => ({dt_txt: e.dt_txt, etc}))`